# Unity - DependencyAttribute or Interface Inheritance for constructor injection

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

What is suggested practice regarding constructor injection with Unity?
What of next two examples is better practice from DI point of view? Is there better solution?

(These examples are simple illustrations)

```
public interface ICircle
{
      double Radius{get;set;}
}

Container.RegisterType<ICircle, SmallCircle>("Small");
Container.RegisterType<ICircle, BigCircle>("Big");

public class Bike{
   Public Bike([Dependency("Big") ICircle bigCircle, Dependency("Small") ICircle smallCircle) {     }
}
```

Or this, more strongly typed solution...

```
public interface IBigCircle : ICircle
{
    // **Empty interface**
}

Container.RegisterType<ICircle, SmallCircle>();
Container.RegisterType<IBigCircle, BigCircle>();

public class Bike{
   Public Bike( IBigCircle bigCircle, ICircle smallCircle) {     }
}
```

What worries me is that number of empty interfaces can grow over the time in this second solution.

Comment: The first approach is bad since it makes your classes know which implementations they are going to receive. And the second approach is an attempt to work around the problem. I suggest that you use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) whenever you have multiple implementations of the same interface. See [this article here](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html) for a related discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the first code sample is better than the first because it is not cluttering the design with unnecessary interfaces (e.g. `IBigCircle`).  However, both examples are not great.  The problem with the first sample is that using the `DependencyAttribute` couples the container to the application which is something to avoid.

So if the two examples are not great than what is a better alternative?

Here are a few.  The first alternative is to use an `InjectionFactory` to instantiate the required object:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<ICircle, SmallCircle>("Small");
container.RegisterType<ICircle, BigCircle>("Big");

container.RegisterType<Bike>(new InjectionFactory(
    c => new Bike(c.Resolve<ICircle>("Big"), c.Resolve<ICircle>("Small"))));
```

In the above example the container is used to resolve the "Big" and "Small" registered ICircle implementations.  Also, because we use `new Bike` we get compile time checking of the constructor arguments.

Another similar approach is to use an `InjectionConstructor` to specify the objects to inject:

```
container.RegisterType<Bike>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedParameter<ICircle>("Big"),
    new ResolvedParameter<ICircle>("Small")
    ));
```

The above tells Unity to use the Constructor with two `ICircle` Parameters and the `ResolvedParameter` indicates to resolve the specific `ICircle` by name.

Another approach you could use (but probably wouldn't be the first choice but is included here for completeness) is to specify what types are required at resolve time instead of registration time:

```
container.Resolve<Bike>(
    new ParameterOverride("bigCircle",   container.Resolve<ICircle>("Big")),
    new ParameterOverride("smallCircle", container.Resolve<ICircle>("Small")));
```

Comment: This example with InjectionConstructor seems much more appropriate than original two examples that I wrote. What I like is that classes that implement ICircle will not have any dependency to Unity. They can even be in a project that does not reference it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach, your classes know the name of the dependencies that would be injected into them. So this code:

```
[Dependency("Big")] ICircle bigCircle
```

Is not very much different from:

```
bigCircle = ServiceLocator.Locate<ICircle>("Big");
```

This is the [service locator anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).

Your class is basically guiding the container to inject a dependency with a specific name. It is involved in the composition process. When doing proper dependency injection, classes should have a passive role only.

Your second approach is an attempt to solve this problem by introducing yet another interface that represents the same abstraction just to please the container. What happens if you have a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for `ICircle`, do you have to create a similar decorator for `IBigCircle`?

A better approach is to do dependency injection without a container. This is called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). See [this article](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html) for a related discussion. Pure DI is specially useful when you have multiple implementations of a single interface (which is true in many applications).

Comment: I see and I agree generally. Both examples seem wrong. And regarding your question regarding decorator, well maybe - yes.Regarding Pure DI concept, I am not familiar with it. I wall go through it and I will write my feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

The example carries some assumptions with it. For example, it's suggested from reading the interface names that `IBigCircle` would have a larger radius than `ISmallCircle` but that depends on the implementation, not on the name of the interface. The interfaces can't guarantee what their names imply. (Just like `IEnumerable<string> bigList, IEnumerable<string> smallList` can't really enforce which is bigger.)

If what matters is that one is bigger than the other you could just depend on two `ICircles` and determine at runtime which is bigger. Or you could have an `IWheels` interface consisting of two `ICircles` and use some sort of factory to create acceptable pairs of circles out of available implementations.

Comment: You can ignore interface names. I tried to see what approach fits better with Unity DI in case when I have multiple implementations of the same interface.